# Ask question text area is corrupted

Tags: support

I am unable to ask question. As you can see in attached image, my text area is covered with "editing help" buttons. This must be some issue in my laptop. Any idea what causes this and how I can fix this?

I tried in all browsers edge, firefox and chrome on windows 10.

[image: As Below]

**UPDATE**

I checked console using firebug. I see some script is inserting div tag in infinite loop. It stops only after I click stop when browser warns me unresponsive script.

[image]

Comment: Asked from different machine. happens on meta too.

Comment: Have you checked each browser's console log? It may provide hints to point undesired behavior on your machine.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: http://sstatic.net is a proper _"domain intended for static content delivered to the Stack Exchange family of websites"_. So, it's not a malicious script. Did you clear the cache on the afflicted browser?

Comment: Yes I did clear cache. It happens on all browsers chrome and firefox internet explorer and edge

Comment: Does it happen when using https? (my thought is that some proxy may be clobbering your traffic)

Comment: well i alreday asked this question months ago and what i got is dv and then  closed it..hope you won't get :)

Comment: Maybe the same as this? [Editor toolbar bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284896/editor-toolbar-bug)